# Prove $a (x^2 + y^2) \gg 4 x y$ with $a \geq 2$ and $x,y >0$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

I am trying to prove

$$a (x^2 + y^2) \gg 4 x y$$

with $a \geq 2$ and $x,y >0$. Maybe $x,y > 0$ is not needed in the proof. I just added them as in my problem I am working with positive
$x,y$. The figures below provide an indication that the inequality holds with $a = 2$ and $a=3$. It seems that working with bigger values of $a$ the disparity between the left hand side (LHS) and the right hand side (RHS) of the inequality increases abruptly. Could you please someone provide a way to prove the inequality analytically? In addition, is there any way to find the rate of change in the disparity between the LHS and the RHS as $a$ increases? Any help is highly appreciated.

[image]

[image]

Comment: If $a\geq 2$, then $a(x^2+y^2)\geq 2(x^2+y^2)$. It then follows from $x^2+y^2-2xy=(x-y)^2\geq 0)$.

Comment: It is easy to deduce this via AM/GM.

Comment: According to the toy examples, it seems that the disparity between the LHS and the RHS  of the inequality increases abruptly as $a$ increases from 2 to 3. Is it possible to quantify the rate of change in the disparity between the LHS and the RHS of the inequality w.r.t. $a$?

Comment: @bluebril thanks for the response. According to the toy examples, it seems that the disparity between the LHS and the RHS of the inequality increases abruptly as $a$
 increases from 2 to 3. Is it possible to quantify the rate of change in the disparity between the LHS and the RHS of the inequality w.r.t. $a$?

Comment: If $a\rightarrow \infty$, then the difference $\rightarrow \infty$ also. EDIT: Whoops my bad. I don't think this is what you need.

Comment: I think it looks like it abruptly increases because you vary the $x,y$. If you fix them and vary $a$ instead, the difference is just linear in $a$.

Comment: Do you really mean $\gg$, and not simply $\ge$?

Comment: Please answer my question, Thoth.

Comment: @GerryMyerson, I apologize for the delay in my response. To clarify, I meant to use the symbol $\geq$ instead of $\gg$. My intention was to emphasize how rapidly the disparity between the LHS and the RHS in the inequality grows as $\alpha$ increases. As `marty cohen` pointed out, we have $\alpha(x^2+y^2)\geq 4xy$.

To quantify the rate of growth, we can define $f(\alpha) = \frac{4xy}{\alpha(x^2+y^2)} \leq 1$. As $\alpha$ approaches infinity, we have $f(\alpha) \to 0$. According to `bluebril`, this convergence occurs at a linear rate.

Comment: Maybe it might be more appropriate to use the symbol $\geq$ instead of $\gg$.

Comment: The symbol $\gg$ is not usually used to mean "much greater than", or anything along those lines. It is usually used as follows: $f(x)\gg g(x)$ means there is a positive constant $C$ such that for all sufficiently large values of $x$, $f(x)>Cg(x)$. So, for example, $x\gg x+1$, since $x>(1/2)(x+1)$ for all $x>1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If
$a \ge 2$ then
$a=2+c$ where
$c \ge 0$.

Then

$\begin{array}\\
a (x^2 + y^2) - 4 x y
&=(2+c) (x^2 + y^2) - 4 x y\\
&=c(x^2 + y^2)+2(x^2+y^2) - 4 x y\\
&=c(x^2 + y^2)+2(x^2+y^2-2xy)\\
&=c(x^2 + y^2)+2(x-y)^2\\
&\ge 0\\
\end{array}
$